# How do I calculate number of words and number of unique words contained within a list of a column across all rows of my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I generated a column `df['adjectives']` in my pandas dataframe that has a list of all the adjectives from another column, `df['reviews']`.

The values of `df['adjectives']` are in this format, for example:

> `['excellent', 'better', 'big', 'unexpected', 'excellent', 'big']`

I would like to create a new column that counts the total number of words in `df['adjectives']` as well as the number of 'unique' words in `df['adjectives']`.

The function should iterate across the entire dataframe and apply the counts for each row.

For the above row example, I would want `df['totaladj']` to be 6 and `df['uniqueadj']` to be 4 (since 'excellent' and 'big' are repeated)

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('./data.csv')

df['totaladj'] = df['adjectives'].str.count(' ') + 1

df.to_csv('./data.csv', index=False)
```

The above code works when counting the total number of adjectives, but not the unique number of adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the type of behavior that you are looking for?

Based off of your description I assumed that the values in the **adjectives** column are a string formatted like a list e.g. **"['big','excellent','small']"**

The code below converts the strings to a list using **split()**, and then gets the length using **len()**.Finding the number of unique adjectives is done by converting the list to a set before using **len()**.

```py
df['adjcount'] = df['adjectives'].apply(lambda x:  len(x[1:-1].split(',')))

df['uniqueadjcount'] =  df['adjectives'].apply(lambda x:  len(set(x[1:-1].split(','))))
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @youngguv if this answer solved your issue, please make sure you mark it as accepted answer.